# split a string and append the split result using python

Tags: r, python-2.7

I am new to Python and I am exploring on using Python to do this task. I have an [Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mwoR.png) that looks like this.

I would like to split a string and append the split result. Please find the [screenshot below which shows the way I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT9G1.png)

I can use either python (or) R. Have you guys implemented anything like this using python? If so, can you share your ideas?

I would like this output to be saved in a different excel file.

Answer (score 0):

This is what all i can depict from your question, how you can read from excel file and split them

```
import xlrd

loc = ("path of file")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
word = (sheet.cell_value(3,2))
print(word.split(' '))
```

To append the string you have to just use a loop for `str1+str2`